# instagram basic display api Exchange Code for Token returns 400 OAuthException Invalid platform app

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram

had some issues with this, thought i could share some input:

After setting up my Instagram app, I used the platform specific App ID, not Facebook app ID.

I navigated to my Facebook app Dashboard Products > Instagram > Basic Display and copied the Instagram App ID, but I'm still getting Invalid platform app error.

Here's my code:

```py
from my_variables import client_id, client_secret, grant_type
import requests


def exchange_for_access_token(code, redirect_uri):
    r = requests.post(
        'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token',
        data={
            'client_id': client_id,
            'client_secret': client_secret,
            'grant_type': grant_type,
            'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
            'code': code,
        },
    )
    r.raise_for_status()
    return r.json()
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue after disabling the ssl verification and adding 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' HEADER.

Here's my code example:

```py
from my_variables import client_id, client_secret, grant_type
import requests


def exchange_for_access_token(code, redirect_uri):
    r = requests.post(
        'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token',
        data={
            'client_id': client_id,
            'client_secret': client_secret,
            'grant_type': grant_type,
            'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
            'code': code,
        },
        headers={
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        verify=False,
    )
    r.raise_for_status()
    return r.json()
```

Comment: It worked; also I didn't need to add `verify=False`.
Thank you!